# Implicit Differentiation!

Tags: derivatives

When a certain kind of coffee is selling at p dollars per pound, consumers will buy $D(p) = 4374/p^2$ pounds of the coffee per week

It is also known that t weeks from now, the price of this coffee will be $p(t) = 0.2t^2 + 0.1t + 6$ dollars per pound.

**At what rate will the demand for this coffee be changing with respect to time 10 weeks from
now?**

I'm kinda confused with this question, how should I do it?
Step by step explanations will be appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: Can you get the expression for demand in terms of time?

Comment: @Element118 No idea. Can I do that? I only know that dD/dT = dD/dp x dp/dt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule,
$$\frac{d D}{dt}=\frac{d D}{dp}\frac{dp}{dt}$$
From which,
\begin{align}
\frac{d D}{dp} &= -\frac{8748}{p^{3}} \\
\frac{dp}{dt}  &= 0.4t+0.1
\end{align}
Using the definition of $p(t)$,
$$\frac{d D}{dp} = -\frac{8748}{(0.2t^{2}+0.1t+6)^{3}}$$
Hence
$$\frac{d D}{dt} =-\frac{8748(0.4t+0.1)}{(0.2t^{2}+0.1t+6)^{3}} $$
the information in the question asks you to compute the rate of change of Demand in $10$ weeks from now; this means in the above derivative you substitute $t=10$ and simplify. I'll leave that part to you.

All the best, 
Bacon.

Comment: Thank you almighty Bacon!!! You da MVP.